# Use node custom field to choose my posts background

Tags: entities, media, 8, theming

I'm building my first Drupal 8 theme and I'd like to add the possibility to change the page background header when editing a post.

I've added a custom field in my post type to provide an image to each post. It works, I can add an image and access the image url on my page.

The problem is that I can't find a way to add inline css to my page to add the background-image property.

Here's my code, located in my .theme file :

```
function hugo_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');

  if($node->field_image_de_fond->entity) {
        $image_url = $node->field_image_de_fond->entity->url();
        $css_code = ".header-bg-home { background-image: url('" . $image_url . "'); }";
        $page['#attached']['css'][] = array(
              'data' => $css_code,
              'type' => 'inline',
              'scope' => 'header'
            );
  }

}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

As it's my first D8 theme I'm really not sure about the way am doing that, it would probably be better to write a custom css stylesheet with the image url as a parameter, but I've no idea how to do that. Also, I'm not sure about the `\Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');` in terms of performances.

Comment: Someone to help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a preprocess function ? Instead use a template =).

Here is an example of how I achieve this functionality for the content type "Article" + the image field.

**node--article.html.twig**

```
  <header class="main-header post-head " style="background-image: url({{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri)}})"> </header>
```

I added the image on the header on top of my template and use the file_url to get the image from the field_image.

```
  {{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri)}}
```

This will allow you to get the image URL.

Few wrappers + classes to make it this image as background image. And every node will have a custom image background.